# Find document with specific value from array within an array of subdocuments

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I want to find all documents that have, in an array of subdocuments, a value that matches anything within another array.

Documents

```
{
    storeName: String,
    location: String,
    inventory: [{
        itemName: String,
        price: Number,
        otherDetail: String,
    }]
}
```

Example array

```
let itemNames = ["chair", "bed", "table"];
```

I am using aggregate.  I need to find all stores (documents) that have in the inventory any of the itemNames in the array.

Comment: FYI, if you answered/saw my other question, sorry, I got my data structure wrong and thought it would be better to just ask another question.

Comment: What you have tried? what you are getting after try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator along with [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) to filter from your nested array.

```
var filter = {
    inventory: {
        $elemMatch: {
            itemName: {
                $in: ["chair", "bed", "table"]
            }
        }
    }
};

db.collection.find(filter);
```

---

With `aggregate` -

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        $match: {
            inventory: {
                $elemMatch: {
                    itemName: {
                        $in: ["chair", "bed", "table"]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
];

db.collection.aggregate(pipeline);
```

Comment: The problem with this though, is that I am using aggregation and I cannot use $elemMatch with aggregation.

Comment: @LeeMorgan updated my answer for usage with Aggregate